# ListView stutters while scrolling, using Picasso

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, picasso

I have a view, that is inflated from within a FragmentActivity. This view contains a listview of custom layouts that contain an imageview. the images are downloaded from urls. I'm using Picasso to handle the image cache etc. I have implemented literally every solution i have been able to find, yet my listview still scrolls terribly.

**Playlist**

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    playlistFrame = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_frame, parent, false);

    swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) playlistFrame.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    playlistView = (ListView) playlistFrame.findViewById(R.id.playlist_view);
    playlistView.setOnScrollListener(new PlaylistScrollListener(context, SCROLL_TAG));
    swipeContainer = (FrameLayout) playlistFrame.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
    playlist = list;
    videoPosition = 0;
    Report listContents[] = new Report[list.size()];

    list.toArray(listContents);
    playlistView.setAdapter(getListAdapter(listContents));
...
    private ArrayAdapter<Report> getListAdapter(final Report item[]) {

    return new ArrayAdapter<Report>(context, R.layout.playlist_item_frame, item) {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item_frame, parent, false);
            }

            final TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_title);
            title.setText(item[position].getTitle());

            final TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_date);
            date.setText(item[position].getDate());

            final TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_description);
            description.setText(item[position].getDescription());

            final ImageView itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_thumb);
            itemImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            Picasso.with(context).load(item[position].thumbnailURLs.standard)
                    .tag(SCROLL_TAG)
                    .fit()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.playlist_thumbnail)
                    .error(R.drawable.playlist_thumbnail)
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(itemImage);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    selectPost(position);
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    };
}
```

**Playlist Scroll Listener**

```
public class PlaylistScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
private final Context context;
private String scrollTag;

public PlaylistScrollListener(Context context, String tag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.scrollTag = tag;
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    final Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(context);
    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
        picasso.resumeTag(scrollTag);
    } else {
        picasso.pauseTag(scrollTag);
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                     int totalItemCount) {
    // Do nothing.
}
}
```

any help improving this scroll issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Traceview and related tools to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: @CommonsWare the loading of the images is causing the lag

Comment: That's not especially specific, which is why I suggested that you use Traceview and related tools to determine where your time is being spent. There are many steps involved in the work that Picasso is doing; you need to isolate specifically where the time is going, particularly the time spent on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare well 9.4% of usage is from the Adapter call, of that 9.4% , 99% of it is picasso .hunt()->run()->load()

Comment: Stating the obvious probably, but where is your ViewHolder pattern? You're calling `findViewById` quite a few times for each `getView` call. This might not be the issue, but it's definitely a place to start to optimise.

Comment: @Darwind just added a viewholder pattern to the process, naturally it helped, for cells that already had the images downloaded into cache (scrolling back up etc), but the downloading of images causes absolutely unbearable lag.

Comment: How big are the images you're trying to download - both pixel and size wise. Is the endpoint publicly available so maybe I could try it out?

Comment: @Darwind theyre roughly 400x400 px and theyre range from 15-25kb, and no its not public yet, sorry

Comment: Ok, that's weird then. What is the reason for using `Picasso.resumeTag` and `Picasso.pauseTag` in your case? You could potentially build up a quite big queue of items to be loaded in the end.

Comment: @Darwind that was my first attempt to improve functionality. which didn't really help at all